# Jersey on Tomcat 7 throws java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument

Tags: java, exception, jersey, tomcat7, socketexception

I've built two Jersey web applications and running both of them on Tomcat 7. For the sake of simplicity I'll call them "App A" and "App B".

There is an endpoint on "App A" that internally makes an HTTP request to "App B".

When consuming this endpoint on "App A" in Java, it **occasionally** returns the following exception when trying to make the request to "App B":

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:67)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:58)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:262)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke(CPoolProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.receiveResponseHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
```

The exception happens exactly where "App A" tries to make a request to "App B". This happens with Tomcat 7 running in Eclipse, and also when it runs standalone. And it happens with both MacOSX `10.9` and Centos `6`.

Trying to make the same request with Python, it **ocassionally** returns the same exception:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 361, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /mashape-apis-database-server/v1/tags/ (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: '')
```

I'm running Java `1.7.0_25`, Jersey `2.4.1`, Tomcat `7`, and MacOSX `10.9` (or Centos `6`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the apps on separate Virtual Machines fixed the problem.